# Select column_name from (Select) Pervasive

Tags: select, pervasive

I'm trying to create a dynamic cursor with pervasive and I want to know the name of columns on any query for add a loop with    "FETCH NEXT FROM"  .

Comment: The question is not clear.  Do you mean you want to ask for the list of columns for a table?

Comment: I want to know if is possible to do something like -SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM(SELECT A.*,B.* FROM TABLEA  A JOIN TABLEB B  ON ... )

Answer (score 4):

Coming to this very late, but here's my 2 cents. IMHO your added comment is not very enlightening. I understand the question as asking about meta-information. Column names can be obtained by querying the system tables, like

`SELECT Xe$Name FROM X$Field INNER JOIN X$File ON Xf$Id = Xe$File WHERE Xf$Name = '<tablename>' ORDER BY Xe$Offset;`

and using the result set in a variable.